# <tx:annotation-driven /> giving error

Tags: spring, annotations

I am using  as shown :

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
     xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"  
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"  
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task   
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

            <tx:annotation-driven/>
```

and the error it is giving is :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'chatSessionDAO' 
defined in file [/local/jboss-eap-4.2/jboss-as/server/mercer02/deploy/mercerhr.ear/mercer.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/mercer/chat/app/dao/ChatSessionDAO.class]: 
Initialization of bean failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: 
(class: com/mercer/chat/app/dao/ChatSessionDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c2bd3f90$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bc114739, 
method: invoke signature: (ILjava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;) Inconsistent stack height 2 != 1
```

here is my ChatSessionDAO class :

```
    @Repository("chatSessionDAO")
@Transactional
public class ChatSessionDAO extends MercerChatDAO {

    /** mySessionFactory */
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mySessionFactory")
    private LocalSessionFactoryBean mySessionFactory;

    /** chatAlertsDO */
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("chatAlertsDO")
    private MHRContChatAlertsDO chatAlertsDO;

    /**
     * Method to retrieve chat session objects for a particular id
     * 
     * @param chatSessionQO
     * @return
     * @throws MercerException 
     */
    public List<?> retrieveSessionInfo(ChatSessionQO chatSessionQO) throws MercerException {
        Criteria criteria = null;
        List<?> lstReturn = null;
        try {

            long chatSessionId = chatSessionQO.getChatSessionId();
            Long chatSessionIdLong = new Long(chatSessionId);
            log.info("creating criteria for chatsession");
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = mySessionFactory.getObject();
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            criteria = session.createCriteria(MHRContChatSessionDO.class, "chatSession").add(
                    Restrictions.eq("id", chatSessionIdLong));
            if (criteria != null) {
                lstReturn = processQuery(criteria);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error :::", e);
            throw new MercerException("No transaction");
        }
        return lstReturn;
    }
```

.....other such methods

The interesting thing is when I doing the same thing on my local machine(jdk 1.5, spring 3.0.3,, hibernate 3.0,windows OS, jboss) it poses no problem at all but when the same thing is done on a remote machine with everything remaining same accept ths OS which is Unix, it gives the above error. how to go about this issue now ?

Comment: Exact same JDK builds, just different OS? Is the app being compiled under the Unix JDK? Once it is, does the same error occur?

Comment: Ya exact same JDK just different OS....app being compiled under Unix JDK..thats true.. and the same error is occuring again. Also is @Transactional meant to be used only with AOP ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that JBoss and Spring are manipulating the exact same piece of the ChatSessionDAO's byte code.

As a workaround, you can run it with:

```
-Xverify:none
```

to get rid of this error.

I would also recommend to do two things:

- Post it on the JBoss [forum](http://community.jboss.org/threads) ( may be a bug with `jboss-eap-4.2` )
- Do not transact on a DAO level => always prefer the Service layer, as it clearly defines a unit of work that needs to be atomic